# jQuery Inputpicker plugin: Field not responsive, but the arrow reaches other side

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-plugins

Any idea why this would happen? If you notice, the down arrow is all the way on the right, but the field does not stretch to there. If I make "responsive" to "false", it cuts off the dropdown. This plugin does not have many options, so I don't see what else I can do. I also don't find any other plugins that allow me to use entire table rows as drop-down menu choices. TIA

http://www.inputpicker.com/www/

Here is my JS code:

```
$('#select_litters_dd').inputpicker({
  data: json,
  fields:[
    {name:'cagecard',text:'Cage Card'},
    {name:'dob',text:'Date of Birth'},
    {name:'wean_date',text:'Wean Date'},
    {name:'litter_died_date',text:'Litter Died Date'}
  ],
  headShow: true,
  fieldText : 'cagecard',
  fieldValue: 'cagecard',
  responsive: true,
  autoOpen: false,
});
```

HTML element:

```
<input class="form-control" id="select_litters_dd" value="Select Litter">
```

Non-responsive screenshot:
[image: non-responsive]

Responsive screenshot:
[image: responsive]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I realized I could screw the whole responsive thing and just make the width 230%, and it worked well enough.

```
$('#select_litters_dd').inputpicker({
  data: json,
  fields:[
    {name:'cagecard',text:'Cage Card'},
    {name:'dob',text:'Date of Birth'},
    {name:'wean_date',text:'Wean Date'},
    {name:'litter_died_date',text:'Litter Died Date'}
  ],
  headShow: true,
  fieldText : 'cagecard',
  fieldValue: 'cagecard',
  responsive: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  width: '230%'
});
```